# How to effeciently track dependency version changes?

Tags: php, semantic-versioning

I'm currently working on a PHP driven website that has a number of dependencies via [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Recently, a dependency had a minor version (as per [SemVer](http://semver.org/)) change with a backwards compatibility breaking change in it. The website broke unexpectedly. I updated my dependency version number to something more precise, like `1.2.16` instead of `1.*`.

But this makes versions harder to track, because minor versions change often.

**How do you keep track of dependencies in a way that is both simple and avoids breaking changes to break your project**?

Comment: You were doing the right way to be honest. Who ever maintained the package that introduced a breaking change in a minor version like that is ***doing it very wrong***. I'm not really sure you can account for that sort of thing outside of being very specific with your versions...

Comment: @Bulk can't agree more.

Comment: Does the dependent library explicitly follow SemVer? i.e., does the documentation explicitly mention that they follow Semantic Versioning?

Answer (score 0):

> How do you keep track of dependencies in a way that is both simple and avoids breaking changes to break your project?

Never take automatic updates to live production sites.  You probably shouldn't take them to developer sites either, but that depends on how many developers are involved and the rate of changes raining in.  Best practice is to setup a branch and matching test site where such updates are allowed.  You can run periodic (daily, hourly, whatever...) build/test cycles of your project and site, then automatically generate dependency configurations that extend the stated ranges to whatever has been tested/proven good and check those into the active developer branch(es) where they will eventually find their way to dev/test and product site(s).